# Increasing integer during a loop

Tags: loops, elixir

I'm trying to increase a variable only during certain conditions

```
Enum.reduce(items, 0, fn item, acc  ->
  if item.condition do
    acc = acc+1
    Logger.info acc
  end
end)
```

But i get

```
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
```

Comment: And what is the problem or question?

Comment: acc is not increasing as i did, question is what's the proper way of doing this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The result returned by the function is used as the accumulator for the
>   next iteration, recursively.

`Logger.info` returns `:ok` so you probably don't want that to be your last line.

You must also return `acc` if the condition doesn't meets.

Try with:

```
Enum.reduce(items, 0, fn item, acc  ->
  if item.condition, do: acc + 1, else: acc
end)
```